# Flood requests to an action causes unpredictable behavior - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Asp.Net MVC 5 - I have a table in database which has three column: Id (primary key), CreateDateTime and DeleteDateTime.
DeleteDateTime of last inserted item is null and table has one item with empty DeleteDateTime at any time.

here is my code in action (inside controller):

```
//find active row in database
var activeRow = db.TableName.SingleOrDefault(t => !t.DeleteDateTime.HasValue);

//if there is no any active row
if (activeRow == null)
{
    db.TableName.Add(new TableName()
    {
        DeleteDateTime = null,
        CreateDateTime = DateTime.Now
    });
}
else
{
    //deactive selected row
    activeRow.DeleteDateTime = DateTime.Now;

    //add new row which is active (DeleteDateTime is null)
    db.TableName.Add(new TableName()
    {
        DeleteDateTime = null,
        CreateDateTime = DateTime.Now
    });
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

The problem arises when action get multiple requests at a time. in this code table should not have more than one item with empty DeleteDateTime but I test my action with many request at the same time and I see this result:
[result in database (tow null item with same CreateDateTime)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifOvn.png)

Comment: Lets say you have 2 requests that come in close together.You get the active row at the start of your code. if another request comes in before the first save changes is called, the second request will also grab the same activeRow the first request did.

Comment: **Yes**, that's exactly what happens

Comment: Where are you using this exactly? Are you using this to track user input/user actions on a grid?

Comment: I using this in an action in my controller (asp.net mvc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: i solve the problem by add unique index to "DeleteDateTime" column.(in other cases that unique index is not solution, we can use from trigger)

```
    [Index("IX_DeleteTime", IsUnique = true)]
    public DateTime? DeleteDateTime { get; set; }
```